# integer variables same as factor variables for regression in R

Tags: r

I wanted to know if we have a value of type integer in R, how can we use in regression? Will the behavior be similar to a qualitative factor variable or integer will behave differently. If the integer is something like number of months, I don't know if I should convert the number of months to numeric or not. The response is a continuous variable.

Comment: I find this question a bit vague at this point. What do you want to do? As in, what is the purpose of your study? What is your response variable? What is your setup? How many predictors? You'll have to explain your entire problem and what you're trying to do..

Comment: The purpose of the study is to fit regression model with a set of predictors. There are 20 available variables to choose from, some of which are numeric,factor and of integer type. I cannot disclose the complete problem perhaps because it is part of my assignment.

Comment: Please **edit your original post** to add these info. You are asking for a regression question without telling whether your response is continuous or categorical, and without any information about the nature of your predictors and the purpose of your regression. It is vague, I'm sorry. Vote to close. As you question stands, it can be used as anything is the answer.

Comment: DWin gave you a long answer, but a short one is: integer will behave like any continuous variable. If you want to do analysis for categories, convert (or use in formula) to factors.

Comment: Arun, I have edited my post to include the information that my response is continuous. My reason for non-disclosure of detailed information is maintaining the honor code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the class of a variable are integer, there will will be only one coefficient produced. The coefficient will be the estimated difference in outcome for a one unit change. You do have the option of wrapping `factor` around the variable in the formula, if you desire the variable to be considered multinomial.  If the class is an unordered factor there will be n-1 coefficients produced. The factor class variable coefficients will be the difference of the means for single levels compared to the reference level.